# Enabling Ethernet in CANoe

Tags: canoe

I have installed ethernet driver but Ethernet is not showing up in Measurement set up. Also when I load blf files with ethernet log, software prompts for register bus Ethernet

Answer (score 0):

You need to set ethernet in Hardware-> channel usage
Add Eth network in simulation setup
Configure eth in Simulation-> TCP/Ip stack
Configure ETH hardware
In measurement setup you can add for example ETH trace